# I keep getting the error "The column -column name- was specified multiple times for -table name-"

Tags: sql

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerAddress
AS
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.EmailAddress, C.LastName, C.FirstName, B.Line1, B.Line2, B.City, B.State, B.ZipCode, S.Line1, S.Line2, S.City, S.State, S.ZipCode 
FROM Customers C JOIN Addresses S ON C.ShippingAddressID = S.AddressID, Customers U JOIN Addresses B ON U.BillingAddressID = B.AddressID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ina view, You can't have same name for two columns. In your query B.Line1 and S.Line1 have same names like any others. You need to change one of them to be different from other.

```
CREATE VIEW CUSTOMERADDRESS
AS
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.EMAILADDRESS, C.LASTNAME, C.FIRSTNAME, B.LINE1 AS BLINE1, B.LINE2 AS AS BLINE2, B.CITY AS BCITY, B.STATE AS BSTATE, B.ZIPCODE AS BZIP, 
S.LINE1, S.LINE2, S.CITY, S.STATE, S.ZIPCODE 
FROM CUSTOMERS C JOIN ADDRESSES S ON C.SHIPPINGADDRESSID = S.ADDRESSID, CUSTOMERS U JOIN ADDRESSES B ON U.BILLINGADDRESSID = B.ADDRESSID;
```

Answer (score 2):

The resulting view, like a table, should have unique column names.
Your code:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerAddress
AS
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.EmailAddress, C.LastName, C.FirstName, 
B.Line1, B.Line2, B.City, B.State, B.ZipCode, 
S.Line1, S.Line2, S.City, S.State, S.ZipCode 
FROM Customers C JOIN Addresses S ON C.ShippingAddressID = S.AddressID, 
Customers U JOIN Addresses B ON U.BillingAddressID = B.AddressID;
```

Already have names in B.* and S.* the same. Column names should be unique in the target view.

You can make a column name unique by changing it for example:

```
S.Line1 as SLine1, S.Line2 as SLine2, ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ', Customers U' at the end of your first join.

Instead of

JOIN Addresses S ON C.ShippingAddressID = S.AddressID, Customers U

Try

JOIN Addresses S ON C.ShippingAddressID = S.AddressID

Answer (score 0):

Your join looks really funky to me (as in I don't think it will work).  You can't mix joins and the old syntax like you have.

And you have several columns in your select list twice, from two different tables, you'll

need to alias one.

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerAddress
AS
SELECT C.CustomerID
, 
C.EmailAddress
, C.LastName
, C.FirstName
, B.Line1  --DUP
, B.Line2  --DUP
, B.City   --DUP
, B.State  --DUP
, B.ZipCode --DUP
, S.Line1  --DUP
, S.Line2  --DUP
, S.City --DUP
, S.State  --DUP
, S.ZipCode --DUP
```

Comment: You still have duplicate column names

Comment: I wasn't changing them, just showing what the OP had in an easier to read format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between the address columns in the view (pluc you've included Customers twice which will result in a cross join):

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerAddress
AS
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.EmailAddress, C.LastName, C.FirstName, 
    B.Line1 BillingLine1, B.Line2 BillingLine2, B.City BillingCity, B.State BillingState, B.ZipCode BillingZipCode, 
    S.Line1 ShippingLine1, S.Line2 ShippingLine2, S.City ShippingCity, S.State ShippingState, S.ZipCode ShippingZipCode 
FROM Customers C 
JOIN Addresses S ON C.ShippingAddressID = S.AddressID, 
JOIN Addresses B ON C.BillingAddressID = B.AddressID;
```